# Expect send seems not functioning

Tags: send, expect, freeze

Scenario

ftp login

spawn function properly

```
  spawn ftp super.super@xxx.xxx.xxx.com
  using master pty /dev/ncptyp0X
  spawn: returns {2812}
  expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "$"? yes
  expect: set expect_out(0,string) ""
  expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
  expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""
```

expect function properly

```
  expect: does "Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.com.\r\n220 XXXX FTP SERVER 
  2 (Version 1) ready.\r\n331 Password required for SUPER.SUPER
  .\r\nPassword: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "Password:"? yes
  expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Password:"
  expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
  expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.com.\r\n220 
  FTP SERVER  (Version H02 XXXX 23DEC2011) ready.\r\n331 Password requir
  ed for SUPER.SUPER.\r\nPassword:"
```

send after expect shows sending [ Expect -d out send: sending "yyyyy\n" to { exp4 } ]
expect after send get blocked with just space in buffer

```
expect: does " " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ftp>"? no << it hangs here
```

Question needs improvement.

Code

```
set timeout -1
set match_max 60000
set exp_internal 1
spawn ftp super.super@$machineName 
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r" 
expect "ftp>"
```

It hangs after the `expect "ftp>"`

Expect version :5.43.0 m/c:Windows_NT 6 02 8664

Comment: "Question needs improvement." -- I second that.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: FTP into the server yourself and see if `ftp>` is the actual string it returns.

Comment: yes it returns ftp> if i try from outside Expect.

Comment: What are you telling it to do after it expects `ftp>`? Also I'm not sure if you are blanking out your password or it is a variable in a bash script. Is this the whole code?

Comment: it hangs for "ftp>" as buffer contain only  " ". yes password and machine name is input to the script.